# How can I calculate the force that is applied on a tube by another tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Let's say there is two tubes(cylinders with no tops or bottoms) with charges $q_1$ and $q_2$, radii $b_1$ and $b_2$, lengths $l_1$ and $l_2$. These tubes are located along the axis of each other's surfaces like in this figure:
[image: two cylinders along the same axis, separated by a gap]

If the electric field that the first tube creates on a point is;
$$
E = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 + (c-a)^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 + (c+a)^2}}\right)
$$
where $b$ is the radius of the tube, $c-a$ is the distance between the centre of the furthest part of the tube and the point, $c+a$ is the distance between the centre of the closest part of the tube and the point, $q$ is the total cahrge on the tube and 
$\epsilon_0$ is the electric constant. Here is the figure of the tube and the point for those who didn't understand from my description:
[image: variable definitions for one tube]

The question is how can I calculate the force between these two tubes?

Update:The electric field formula I found is not true since it is valid for a point on axis of the cylinder. Thus I would be pleased if you could show me how to solve the problem from the beginning.

Comment: Could you please clarify two things: 1) your formula assumes the two cylinders to have the same radius, but your problem statement seems to imply you want the solution when the radii are different; 2) is the electric field formula that you have only valid on the axis of the cylinder? I assume the answers are 1) need solution for different r1 and r2, and 2) yes.

Comment: Not promising when I will have time… but at least now the problem is well defined and understood. Maybe someone else will get to it before I do, but I hope to have a chance to write these down later. It's going to be messy...

Comment: It would be useful to know exactly what sort of answer you are after: a simple closed form solution almost certainly doesn't exist. If you'd like to understand the physics, and the ideas behind the derivation of the force, there are much more tractable problems that will be more revealing, and for which complete and well-explained solutions already exist in abundance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in five steps (four integrals).

1. Start with the force of two point charges: you know this equation 
   $$F=\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}$$
2. Integrate this force over an infinitesimally thin ring of charge: now you have the force of a ring on an off-axis point (hint: you only need the axial component - the radial components will cancel due to symmetry in the next step). The distance $R$ will be a function of position along the ring (since the point charge is off-axis)
3. Integrate over all possible points that constitute a second ring: now you have the force of one ring on another; with the two rings on the same axis, the force will be along that axis. This is easy since the axial force is the same everywhere (so no difficult integration needed - just multiply by $2\pi$ and take account of the "charge per unit length").
4. Integrate over the length of the first cylinder: now you have the force of a cylinder on a ring. This is a bit harder - you are in essence integrating the force over a series of rings of variable (axial) distance
5. Integrate over the second cylinder: this is the sum of the force between a cylinder and a series of rings of different distance to the cylinder.

Note that your expression for the on-axis force of the cylinder is not terribly helpful since the charges of the second cylinder are off-axis.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have some difficulty understanding this. Do I have to calculate the force with Coulomb's law and aborting the electric field I gave in the question? Also, I literally have no idea how to use integral in the equations so I would be grateful if you could show me how to do it with variables. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give me some more details on how to use axial and radial components in integrals? For example, how should I use the $r$ in the first step? The distance between the centres of the tubes? Also can you explain what do you mean by multiplying by$2\pi$ and taking account of the charge per unit length?

Answer (score 1):

The answers already in here are good; unfortunately the integrals that arise are quite nasty, and don't have solutions in terms of elementary functions. Here is some more detail, in the special case when the tubes have zero length (so they are just charged circular loops), and further they have the same radius $b$, with separation $d$. You'll see that this is plenty nasty already!

By general considerations (dimensional analysis in particular), the force will be directed along the common axis and will take the form
$$
F=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 d^2}f\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)
$$
for some function $f$. All the nontrivial information in the problem is encoded in the function $f$, which tells us how the force depends on the geometry of the setup. It remains to work out what this function looks like. We can get a long way with some physical intuition and limiting cases.

Firstly, the limiting case when the ratio $x=\frac{b}{d}$ of radius to separation is very small. Now the rings essentially become point particles, so we should reduce to Coulomb's law: $f(x) \sim 1$ as $x\to0$.

Now, what happens if we increase the radius while keeping separation fixed? The charge is tending to get more separated, so the forces should be decreasing: we should find that $f(x)$ decreases as $x$ increases.

Finally, the limiting case when $x$ is very large: now, the rings have such a wide radius that locally the problem looks like the force between parallel charged wires, which is $\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{2\pi\epsilon_0 d}$ per unit length, where the $\lambda$s denote charges per unit length. From this, you can work out that $F\sim \frac{1}{2\pi b}\frac{q_1q_2}{2\pi\epsilon_0 d}$,and $f(x)\sim\frac{1}{\pi x}$ as $x\to\infty$.

Now the main physics lesson to draw is that you've now learnt pretty much everything qualitative about the force from these simple considerations without a calculation! Unless you *really* need to, you can stop here...

But I suppose I'll carry on a little further.
Consider two small elements of the circular wires. We can put them at positions $(b\cos\theta_1,b\sin\theta_1,0)$ and $(b\cos\theta_2,b\sin\theta_2,d)$, with ends separated by small angles $\delta \theta_1,\delta \theta_2$. The $\theta$s denote cylindrical polar angles of the positions of the charge elements in question. They carry charges $\frac{\delta \theta_1}{2\pi}q_1,\frac{\delta \theta_2}{2\pi}q_2$. They are separated by distance $r=\sqrt{(b\cos\theta_1-b\cos\theta_2)^2+(b\sin\theta_1-b\sin\theta_2)^2+d^2}=\sqrt{d^2+2b^2(1-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2))}$. The force between them in the $z$-direction (other directions give 0 in the end by symmetry) is hence
$$
\frac{q_1q_2\delta\theta_1\delta\theta_2 d}{(2\pi)^24\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}
$$
from Coulomb's law. The total force is then given by summing over all such elements, which in the limit as they become very small is the integral:
$$
F =\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{q_1q_2d}{(2\pi)^24\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}d\theta_1d\theta_2 \\
=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 d^2} \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left[1+2\frac{b^2}{d^2}(1-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2))\right]^{-3/2}d\theta_1d\theta_2.
$$

Here one of the integrals can be shifted by periodicity to be over $\phi=\theta_1-\theta_2$, and the second will then give simply $2\pi$. The remaining integral is what gives us $f$, which can be simplified to
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left[1+4x^2 \sin^2\left(\frac\phi2\right)\right]^{-3/2}d\phi,
$$
which finally can be evaluated, but only in terms of the Jacobi elliptic integral:
$$
f(x)=\frac{2 E\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4 x^2}}\right)}{\pi  \sqrt{4 x^2+1}}
$$
where $E$ is the special function, the [Complete Elliptic Integral of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Here's a graph of $f$. It has all the properties that we worked out without the messy computation.
[image: Graph of f]

Comment: I've made a few edits, which I hope should address most of your questions. I define $x=b/d$ because it is the only dimensionless parameter left in my reduced problem, so it is the only thing that the answer can depend on in a nontrivial way.

Comment: To extend this to rings of different radii is not too bad; if you have understood the derivation it's just a similar version with slightly messier algebra. To give the answer for cylinders requires doing two more integrals over the lengths of the cylinders, which I am quite sure would be impossible to simplify in any useful way.

Comment: If you can't see how to write down the integrals required to solve for two cylinders, then you haven't understood what's being done. That's very understandable as you've picked a question with very nasty calculations which get in the way seeing what's going on. Ask a simpler question so that you might understand the idea. I've just seen that you've not studied any calculus, in which case these sorts of questions are beyond your current set of skills in any case unfortunately.

Comment: You don't have to use $f$ at all, I just chose to put it in because it captures all the physics, and I don't have to carry around all the annoying constants the whole time. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: The force is $\frac{q_1q_2\delta\theta_1\delta\theta_2 d}{(2\pi)^24\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}$ because it is a single component of the force between the elements, not the whole magnitude. Only the component in the axial direction contributes in the end, and it is this that I compute. If it helps, the $d/r^3$ is the magnitude ($1/r^2$) times the cosine of the angle between the axis of the rings and the line of force joining the elements ($d/r$; adjacent over hypotenuse). See [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law#Vector_form)

Comment: Yes: the force between two particles is directed along the line between them. The component in a direction at an angle of $\theta$ to that line will in general be smaller than the size of the force, by a factor of $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16897/discussion-between-holographer-and-starior).

Answer (score 0):

Without actually providing the mathematical details (which is left for the reader) the basic outline is this:
1.Select a differential segment (a segment of infinitesimal lateral dimensions) on the second cylinder.
2.Write the electric field expression for an infinitesimal charge on the segment.
3.Write the force equation and integrate over the entire surface.

Comment: Unfortunately the expression you have is for an on-axis charge and that doesn't help you solve the problem with this approach. So you need to take a couple of steps back before you can go forward...

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the forces two parallel current-carrying wires exert on one another?

Given two current-carrying wires, $a$, and $b$, we can determine the force exerted on wire $b$ by wire $a$ with $$F=(µ_oI_a/2πr) I_bL$$

Where F is the force exerted, $µ_o$ is the magnetic permeability of a vacuum, $I_a$ is the current flowing through wire $a$, $I_b$ is the current flowing through wire $b$, and $l$ is the length of the section of wire $b$ in the the magnetic field of wire $a$, and $r$ is the distance between the wires.

So, let's work through an example problem.

What is the force wire $a$ exerts on wire $b$ if both wires carry a current of 3 Amps, are 0.25m apart, and if wire $b$ has 1m of wire in the magnetic field of wire $a$.
$$F=(µ_oI_a/2πr)I_bL$$
$$F=(µ_o(3)/2π(0.25))(3)(1)$$
$$F=3(µ_o⋅3/1.57079)$$
$$F=3(µ_o⋅1.9098)$$
$$F=3((4π×10^{−7})⋅1.9098)$$
$$F=3(2.4⋅10^{-6})$$
$$F=7.2⋅10^{-6}\text{ Newtons}$$

I would like to apologize in advance in the case that I misunderstood the question.

I hope I was able to help. I'm going to add this to my favorites list to see what happens. That is, if I didn't answer your question.

Comment: I should note, that the cylinders can probably be considered sections of wire. $L$ would be equal to the length of the cylinder. This force if attractive if the current in the cylinders is traveling in opposite directions, and repulsive if the current travels in the same direction for both of them.